# Accessing Key Vault from Azure using client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, azure-keyvault

I need to access some secret values from Azure key vault in my JavaScript.
It is plain JavaScript, no NPM and node.
Is there any option to get the value directly from JavaScript?
Or I need to write a separate API to retrieve the key vault.
This is not relevant to securing some IDs, I want to know is there any possible option to get the key vault value from client-side.

Here is the link explain [how to retrieve key vault using node.js](https://medium.com/@ayanfecrown/azure-key-vault-node-js-step-by-step-tutorial-af131a78e220)

It is not duplicate of [How to Hide an API Key in Client-Side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237673/how-to-hide-an-api-key-in-client-side-javascript)

I want this to be done in plain javascript.

Comment: @str pls remove duplicate tag, my question is nowhere relavent with the question question which you have tagged. I am stuck with this scenario and i want some answer/suggestion to proceed further. please understand,

Comment: Accessing any secure resource using client side script is a terrible idea. If the client can execute the code, so can any attacker. So you really **should not do this**

Comment: This (despite your protestations) seems to be a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237784/542251). The answer is the same **no**

Comment: Hi, it's a good question, can you provide some things you've tried already to aid people helping you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Hide an API Key in Client-Side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237673/how-to-hide-an-api-key-in-client-side-javascript)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, the "How to Hide an API Key..." question. Indicating so is reflecting a valid opinion on the weaknesses of client side security, however I believe this question is in regard to the specific technology combination of Azure KeyVault and client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a little research, I would suggest this is *not possible* purely with client side JavaScript.

With this chrome developer tools open on the network tab; If you browse to the Azure Portal and look at a secret, you can see the in CORS pre-flight request that the allowed origin is https://portal.azure.com

This essentially means that the only client side JavaScript hosted on portal.azure.com is allowed to use the API which gets secrets.

More details on CORS headers here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

[image: Screen shot of azure portal when requesting a secret]

Comment: Check this out   https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/keyvault-secrets/samples/javascript

Comment: Great tip Roney, the SDK certainly indicates it's possible now!

Comment: Although digging deeper, the examples are for nodejs rather than client side, I haven't had a chance to look at the cors headers yet, I'll try and take another look and update the answer when I get a chance. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: The link Roney gave is broken. @Alex KeySmith Do you have a solution yet? I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi, it was many years back I'm afraid. But it looks like Microsoft have specific documentation on client side use now https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/%40azure/keyvault-secrets_4.6.0/samples/cors/ts/README.md